# How to invoke client.on(..) function in discord.js when I start my server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

GOAL: How do I emit an event inside **client.on("message", message =>...)** function with any given string whenever I start my server.
A workaround would be to type, "test", on a channel where this bot is integrated and listen for the function being emitted inside this above mentioned method.

Working on a discord bot and was wondering how to invoke **client.on(..)**  function call using a command like :

```
client.on("message", "test");
```

My **server.js** file which i run using **npm start** is given below:

```
client.once("ready", () => {
        //some code
    });

client.login(discord_token); // starts the bot up

client.on("message", message => { // runs whenever a message is sent

    //message.content
    var textMessage = message.content;
    textMessage = textMessage.toLowerCase();

    if (textMessage === "test".toLocaleLowerCase()) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: The code produces the following error when I run it

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received type string ('test')  
    at checkListener (events.js:111:11)
```

Comment: is your code not working? Because your code looks fine to me.

Comment: Can you be more specific on which event you want to emit + what information you want to be passed? What is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send the message in the `client.on("ready")` so that it sends your command as soon as it can. For example:

```js
client.once("ready", () => {
                        // vv id of the channel you want to test in
    client.channels.fetch("id").then(channel => {
        channel.send("your message here")
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you this worked exactly as I wanted it to!

To get the channel id I had to: 
Enter Developer mode in discord.
Right click on server>channel to get 'channel' id

Comment: No problem! If this was the answer to your question, could you mark it as the answer by hitting the check mark (✓) next to the answer. Thanks!